# NPM: Missing dist and src directories when trying to install directly from a github url

Tags: github, npm, package.json

An npm package I am using has been forked on github with some bug fixes and I now want to use the forked code in my project until the fork is merged.

In my package.json I change the reference in dependencies from e.g. 
“cool-package”: "^0.10.0"
to “cool-package“: "git://github.com/developer-who-forked/cool-package.git" but this doesn’t work.

If I run npm install after updating the package.json and then go in to node_modules/cool-package/ I don’t see any /src folder or any /dist folder (all the other modules installed via normal npm seem to have at least a /dist folder).

I only see an /example folder and a /test folder alongside a package.json and a README.md. If i’d installed the package by including “cool-package”: "^0.10.0" there would be the src/ and dist/ folders.

The forked repo, or the original repo it was forked from don’t have a /dist folder - it is actually in the .gitignore file. So I think I am missing some build step that is required to create the /dist files when trying to access github repos directly in the package.json.

Comment: Having the same issue - have you figured it out?

Comment: If the git repo you are referencing in your package.json doesn't contain a /dist folder then the solution is this. Clone the git repo locally and then in that cloned repo run npm install followed by npm run build (or whatever the build command is - which will be in the READ.ME). Now come out of that repo and switch in to the repo that you are working on, the one that uses that dependency you just cloned and built. Now from here, you can run and local npm install as follows. npm install /path/to/dependency/, (e.g. npm install ../cool-package/).

Comment: Alternatively, if you have rights to the repo you are referencing in your package.json you can do this. Clone the repo locally, run npm install and npm run build. Ensure that /dist is not in the .gitignore file in the cloned repo, and then git add the /dist folder and the updated .gitignore file, commit and push up to the remote repo. This repo will now have a /dist folder so your package.json will install the .dist folder, which is what you need. Hope this all helps.

Comment: @Tech75 After running `npm run build` I got the build folder with the compiled code. But I didn't see a dist folder. Do I need to rename the build folder as dist?

Comment: @Tech75 Please consider submitting this as an answer, it helped me! (In my case I had to run `npm run-script build`, maybe that would help @DFB, too?)

Comment: I am also  facing the same issue for my redaxios package. You can of course create the dist folder by simply going to the the package in your node_modules and running npm install then running whatever build script is there. The build script will be mentioned in package.json file. 
But this approach is not viable if your project has CI/CD automated process that install packages on every fresh deployment.

Comment: @Tech75's comment should be the accepted answer. Worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

1. commiting `/dist` to gh
2. running `npm install {username}/{repo}.git` instead of manually adding the record to `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

**Just Answered the Question Based on Comments:**

---

I run `npm run-script build` and helped me!

Why it worked -

The issue when installing an npm package directly from a GitHub URL: the missing build step.
When you install a package from npm, it's usually already built and compiled, meaning it has the /dist directory with the production-ready code. However, when you pull directly from GitHub, you're getting the raw source code, which often doesn't include the compiled /dist directory (as it's typically in .gitignore).

Answer (score 0):

The developer has probably added those directories to the `.gitignore`. Since you have forked them, you should be able to safely:

1. Remove those lines from `.gitignore`
2. Rebuild the package again
3. Push the update to your forked repo
4. Reinstall

If you are hoping to have your fork merged, you'll have to roll these changes back. It's probably best to keep these changes in a separate branch.

Incidentally, you can now install directly from git using the `ORGANIZATION_NAME/PACKAGE_NAME` syntax, with some additional features if you need to target by tag, etc.

[NPM Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#github-urls)
[GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry#installing-a-package)