# Why store dist in github repo and npm?

Tags: javascript, github, npm, ecmascript-6, package.json

I saw many repo, that contains dist folder. Why? I think repo should store only source code, without any builds and so on.

Let's look at follow example with ES6 code.

**package.json**

```
{
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "lib"
   ],
  "scripts": {
    "build:lib": "<transform ES6 to ES5 and put it to ./lib folder>",
    "build:umd": "<make a umd module and put it ./dist folder>",
    "build": "npm run build:lib && npm run build:umd",
    "postbuild": "<make minify code>"
    "prepublish": "npm run build"
  }
}
```

I think this is a good way. And I saw several repo that do the same. In this situation github repo would store only `src` and npm repo only `lib` and `dist`.

And now another question. Why store `dist` and `lib` in npm? Most libraries can be installed by executing `npm install` command. And how we know `prepublish` script runs on local `npm install` ([npm-scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)).
So after package have installed we have `lib` and `dist` folders.
I don't understand why store this code in npm if only source code is enough?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that repositories include `dist` directories in order to enable other projects to use them as direct dependencies via git. Compare [package.json docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies), though as of now this doesn't mention that artefacts need to be present.

Compare [NPM: Missing dist and src directories when trying to install directly from a github url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647387/npm-missing-dist-and-src-directories-when-trying-to-install-directly-from-a-git) for the problem that arises if the `dist` directory is not checked in.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, it is also possible to install from a Git repository directly as long as a prepare stage which builds the package is provided:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
     ...
     "prepare": "npm run build"
  },
  ...
}
```

This way, you won't have to store `/dist` folder in the repository itself